# Enyim memcached provider CPU spike

Tags: asp.net, memcached

I've implemented a caching interface and memchanged provider for our website using enyim.  Works great in testing until we get to load testing, where it spikes the CPU of w3wp.exe to near 100%.  We have a configuration property to switch the caching provider back to dotnet's API and the CPU goes back to 5-7%.  Has anyone experienced similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you store something in memcached through enyim, the .NET runtime will perform binary serialization on the stored object. And deserialization when you retrieve. For some types (string, byte[] and some more), enyim implements a more specific and light weight serialization, but most types are serialized by the standard BinaryFormatter. This is processor intensive.

It especially hurts when your code is written towards the in-memory cache in ASP.NET. You will probably have code that thinks that getting something from cache is free. You may get it from cache again and again and again. We had comparable problems when we switched to memcached. If you do some profiling, you'll probably find that you do insanely many reads from cache.

Our experiences with the enyim client have been very positive. We run memcached in an ASP.NET server farm on around 10 nodes and it is very stable. For some forms of data (very often accessed), we prefer the <strike>in-memory</strike> in-process caching of ASP.NET.

Comment: Can you please explain what a memchanged provider is? I thought memcached was in memory only, no serialization to disk.  Thanks!

Comment: Correct, memcached is entirely in-memory. But when you send .NET objects over the network to your memcached server, you'll have to convert your in-memory presentation to a wire-presentation. Serialization is not always to disk, it means to convert your objects (a graph) to a serial presentation (i.e. a sequence of bytes). Oh, and where I said "we prefer the in-memory caching", I should have said "we prefer the in-process caching"

Comment: How do you manage the lifetime of the Memcached Client?  Do you have a singleton for the Application?  Do you call Disponse on it?  I'm chasing down an issue I think deals with my improper handling of the client's object life cycle, and trying to find out best practices.  Thanks!

Comment: We create new instances of MemcachedClient all the time. The client handles connection reuse internally. The client is not designed to keep around for a long time. As it is IDisposable, you probably should wrap it in a using block, but we never do. I don't think the client actually holds any resources that need disposing.

Comment: @TeunD - looks like you're not following the recommendation of the Enyim authors: https://github.com/enyim/EnyimMemcached/wiki/MemcachedClient-Usage - "Important! MemcachedClient is a "heavy object", as in creating and initializing the client is quite expensive.... So, DO NOT create a client every time you want to perform an operation"

Comment: Oops, you're right. I was lying. We actually create it only once. I was confused because we have a wrapper that you can create as often as you need it and it will refer to one central instance of MemcachedClient. Thanks to jaminto for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to also check your serialization and deserialization code for proper object or stream disposal.

I had the exact same w3p.exe spiking to 99% symptoms, and thought for sure it was an Enyim/Membase driver bug, but it wasn't.  It was ours, and it was because we forgot to Dispose() of the MemoryStream after Deserializing every JSON object in our JSON helper class:

```
   public static T DeserializeToObject<T>(this string json)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( json );
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray );

        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        T returnObject = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();  // we forgot this line!
        return returnObject;
    }
```

Comment: The `using` statement will call Dispose for you (plus all your code for the stream will be nicely indented).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx